# kernel panic after starting quicktime video

Tags: crash, quicktime, kernel-panic

I'm getting a kernel panic whenever I start a movie in quicktime player

**When does it happen**

I'm running OSX on an SSD, which was installed in place of my optical drive. I'm trying to open a file on Macintosh HD. It's an mp4 file, and the application to open them is quicktime player, but after a couple of seconds, I get a kernel panic. I've repeated these actions several times, and I keep getting the same result.

**What I've tried:**

I've fixed permissions and performed a disk repair using disk utility, on both the SSD and Macintosh HD.

**Crash report**

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  204039 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          3
Anonymous UUID:                    0F5C514A-96D2-917B-6D39-72A3E70945FB

Mon Aug 26 12:38:06 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f9d213f1a): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff810bdf5000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.4.5/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810adab190 : 0xffffff801b01d626 
0xffffff810adab200 : 0xffffff7f9d213f1a 
0xffffff810adab2d0 : 0xffffff7f9b7ecf1e 
0xffffff810adab390 : 0xffffff7f9b8c112d 
0xffffff810adab3d0 : 0xffffff7f9b8c118e 
0xffffff810adab440 : 0xffffff7f9bb87ed0 
0xffffff810adab570 : 0xffffff7f9b8e9a75 
0xffffff810adab590 : 0xffffff7f9b7f3d50 
0xffffff810adab640 : 0xffffff7f9b7f17d0 
0xffffff810adab840 : 0xffffff7f9b7f2722 
0xffffff810adab920 : 0xffffff7f9c7a5f80 
0xffffff810adab960 : 0xffffff7f9c7b5db7 
0xffffff810adab980 : 0xffffff7f9c7e4e5f 
0xffffff810adab9c0 : 0xffffff7f9c7e4ebd 
0xffffff810adaba00 : 0xffffff7f9c7bbb8f 
0xffffff810adaba50 : 0xffffff7f9c785fe6 
0xffffff810adabae0 : 0xffffff7f9c781d7c 
0xffffff810adabb10 : 0xffffff7f9c77f90b 
0xffffff810adabb40 : 0xffffff801b466363 
0xffffff810adabbc0 : 0xffffff801b4683f3 
0xffffff810adabc20 : 0xffffff801b465e2f 
0xffffff810adabd70 : 0xffffff801b098c01 
0xffffff810adabe80 : 0xffffff801b020b3d 
0xffffff810adabeb0 : 0xffffff801b010448 
0xffffff810adabf00 : 0xffffff801b01961b 
0xffffff810adabf70 : 0xffffff801b0a6536 
0xffffff810adabfb0 : 0xffffff801b0ce9e3 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.2)[96AE69DE-8A37-39D0-B2D3-D8446A6AA670]@0xffffff7f9b78b000->0xffffff7f9ba30fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7f9b6f5000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[6C8CFC18-75F0-3DEF-86C7-CEB2C1FD6BB1]@0xffffff7f9b777000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[990D1A42-DF16-3AB9-ABC1-6A88AC142244]@0xffffff7f9b734000
         com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal(8.1.2)[988EAF3A-3318-3787-8A5A-844830FA1522]@0xffffff7f9ba3c000->0xffffff7f9bd10fff
            dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.2)[96AE69DE-8A37-39D0-B2D3-D8446A6AA670]@0xffffff7f9b78b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7f9b6f5000
         com.apple.GeForce(8.1.2)[7EC545A4-4B57-32F1-8DC3-C31023AFBDCB]@0xffffff7f9c763000->0xffffff7f9c830fff
            dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(8.1.2)[96AE69DE-8A37-39D0-B2D3-D8446A6AA670]@0xffffff7f9b78b000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[6C8CFC18-75F0-3DEF-86C7-CEB2C1FD6BB1]@0xffffff7f9b777000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7f9b6f5000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[990D1A42-DF16-3AB9-ABC1-6A88AC142244]@0xffffff7f9b734000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.4.5)[49FEF732-D7A3-327B-A7AA-6AC5A6E3DCFF]@0xffffff7f9d206000->0xffffff7f9d218fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[1D0BB11E-7D71-34CF-ACC3-57DF01CADA08]@0xffffff7f9d201000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7.3)[1D668879-BEF8-3C58-ABFE-FAC6B3E9A292]@0xffffff7f9b6f5000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.4.5)[4A2C8548-7EF1-38A9-8817-E8CB34B8DCA6]@0xffffff7f9d1ed000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7f9b675000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.7)[6C8CFC18-75F0-3DEF-86C7-CEB2C1FD6BB1]@0xffffff7f9b777000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.7)[990D1A42-DF16-3AB9-ABC1-6A88AC142244]@0xffffff7f9b734000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
12E55

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 896CB1E3-AB79-3DF1-B595-549DFFDF3D36
Kernel slide:     0x000000001ae00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801b000000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 114083936688
last loaded kext at 8560011391: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.1.22 (addr 0xffffff7f9d358000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.1.22
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.1.22
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.1.22
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.1.22
com.quark.driver.Tether64   1.1.0d3
net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.4f2
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.87
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.1.4f2
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.4.5
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.1.4f2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   8.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.1.2
com.apple.GeForce   8.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    8.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.3d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   615.20.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.1b4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.4f2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.1.4f2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.11d0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d0
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    8.1.2
com.apple.NVDAResman    8.1.2
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.7
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.3.0d51
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   530.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220.3
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.66 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0000, 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0000, 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.17)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.4f2 12041, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD5000BEKT-00KA9T0, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series, 128.04 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 4
USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0xfd110000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0237, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfa130000 / 4
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0xfa113000 / 8
```

Comment: Have a look at the answers in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14869/how-can-i-troubleshoot-kernel-panics-on-my-imac, especially the one listing ways to isolate the issue. Please add any additional information gathered that way to your question.

Comment: What QuickTime player version do you use? Does you Mac crash when playing other movies? Where did you get the movie from (downloaded from the Internet, iTunes, ripped, ...)?

Comment: The movie was downloaded from the internet, butnplayed perfectly before. I'll experiment a bit with other video files and report back

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, as per:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5098689?start=0&tstart=0

and:

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088

Have to take to an Apple Store, they should replace the logic board for free.