# What's causing kernel panics?

Tags: mojave, kernel-panic

I'm getting a lot of kernel panics and freezes (many times/day).

I've run an EntreCheck report, but I cannot interpret it. It seems to me to be Backup and Sync to cause it anecdotally, but I think the computer restarted even after I had quit the program.

This is the report, can anyone help?

```
EtreCheck version: 6.0.3 (6A009)
Report generated: 2019-09-24 23:35:11
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 5:34
Performance: Below Average

Problem: Computer is restarting

Major Issues:
  Anything that appears on this list needs immediate attention. 
  System Integrity Protection disabled - System Integrity Protection is disabled. This computer is at risk of malware infection.
  Automatic updates disabled - Automatic updates are disabled. This computer is at risk of malware infection.
  Security updates disabled - Security updates are disabled. This computer is at risk of malware infection.
  Kernel panics - This system has experienced kernel panics that could be related to 3rd party software.
  Stuck iCloud - This machine has a large number of pending iCloud transfers.

Minor Issues:
  These issues do not need immediate attention but they may indicate future problems or opportunities for improvement. 
  Low disk space - This machine is running low on free hard drive space.
  Heavy RAM usage - This machine is using a large amount of RAM.
  High battery cycle count - Your battery may be losing capacity.
  Apps crashing - There have been numerous app crashes.
  Apps with heavy CPU usage - There have been numerous cases of apps with heavy CPU usage.
  Unsigned files - There are unsigned software files installed. They appear to be legitimate but should be reviewed.
  Low performance - EtreCheck report took over 5 minutes to run. This is unusual.
  32-bit Apps - This machine has 32-bits apps will not work after macOS 10.14 “Mojave”.

Hardware Information:
  MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
  MacBook Pro Model: MacBookPro11,4
  1 2,2 GHz Intel Core i7 (i7-4770HQ) CPU: 4-core
  16 RAM - Not upgradeable
    BANK 0/DIMM0 - 8 GB DDR3 1600  ok
    BANK 1/DIMM0 - 8 GB DDR3 1600  ok
  Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 932

Video Information:
  Intel Iris Pro - VRAM: 1536 MB
    Color LCD 3360 x 2100

Drives:
  disk0 - TS240GJDM820 240.06 GB (Solid State - TRIM: No) 
  Internal PCI 8.0 GT/s x2 Serial ATA
    disk0s1 - EFI (MS-DOS FAT32) [EFI] 210 MB
    disk0s2 [APFS Container] 239.85 GB
      disk1 [APFS Virtual drive] 239.85 GB (Shared by 4 volumes)
        disk1s1 - Macintosh HD (APFS) (Shared - 219.04 GB used)
        disk1s2 - Preboot (APFS) [APFS Preboot] (Shared - 46 MB used)
        disk1s3 - Recovery (APFS) [Recovery] (Shared - 510 MB used)
        disk1s4 - VM (APFS) [APFS VM] (Shared - 1.07 GB used)

Mounted Volumes:
  disk1s1 - Macintosh HD
    239.85 GB (Shared - 219.04 GB used - 19.04 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /
    Encrypted

  disk1s4 - VM [APFS VM]
    239.85 GB (Shared - 1.07 GB used - 19.04 GB free)
    APFS
    Mount point: /private/var/vm

Network:
  Interface en4: Moto G (5S) Plus
  Interface en5: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
  Interface en6: iPhone
  Interface en0: Wi-Fi
    802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
  Interface en3: Bluetooth PAN
  Interface bridge0: Thunderbolt Bridge
  iCloud Quota: 1.78 TB available
  iCloud Status: 273368 pending files

System Software:
  macOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132) 
  Time since boot: About 3 hours

Configuration Files:
  /etc/hosts - Count: 70

Notifications:
  /Applications/Noko.app
    one notification

  /Applications/WhatsApp.app
    2 notifications

  /Applications/Slack.app
    100 notifications

  /Applications/openWMail.app
    one notification

  /Applications/Transmit.app
    one notification

  /Applications/Vanilla.app
    6 notifications

Security:
  System Status
  Gatekeeper: App Store and identified developers
  System Integrity Protection: Disabled
  Automatic Updates: Disabled
  Security Updates: Disabled

  Antivirus apps: CleanMyMac

Unsigned Files:
  Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist
    Executable: /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Library/LaunchServices/com.skype.skype.shareagent.bundle/Contents/MacOS/com.skype.skype.shareagent
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
    Executable: /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/PT.updd.plist
    Executable: /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/PT.updd
    Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

  Login Item: /Applications/Thyme.app

32-bit Applications:
  30 32-bit apps

Kernel Extensions:
  /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox
    [Loaded] VBoxDrv.kext (6.0.8)
    [Loaded] VBoxNetAdp.kext (6.0.8)
    [Loaded] VBoxNetFlt.kext (6.0.8)
    [Loaded] VBoxUSB.kext (6.0.8)

  /Library/Extensions
    [Not Loaded] Dropbox.kext (1.10.3 - SDK 10.14)
    [Loaded] Boom2Device.kext (1.2 - SDK 10.12)
    [Not Loaded] intelhaxm.kext (6.2.0 - SDK 10.9)
    [Not Loaded] HoRNDIS.kext (9.2 - SDK 10.11)
    [Loaded] TelestreamAudio.kext (1.1.1 - SDK 10.8)

  /System/Library/Extensions
    [Loaded] eqMac2Driver.kext (1.0 - SDK 10.12)

System Launch Agents:
  [Not Loaded]  18 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  166 Apple tasks
  [Running]  117 Apple tasks

System Launch Daemons:
  [Not Loaded]  35 Apple tasks
  [Loaded]  184 Apple tasks
  [Running]  117 Apple tasks

Launch Agents:
  [Running] com.bjango.istatmenus.agent.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2019-09-23)
  [Running] com.bjango.istatmenus.status.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2019-09-23)
  [Loaded] com.google.keystone.agent.plist (Google, Inc. - installed 2019-09-23)
  [Loaded] com.google.keystone.xpcservice.plist (Google, Inc. - installed 2019-09-23)
  [Loaded] com.microsoft.update.agent.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2019-09-11)
  [Running] net.culater.SIMBL.Agent.plist (wolfgang baird - installed 2019-09-21)

Launch Daemons:
  [Running] PT.updd.plist (? 0  - installed 2017-08-13)
  [Loaded] com.adobe.acc.installer.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2017-10-02)
  [Running] com.bjango.istatmenus.daemon.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2019-09-23)
  [Running] com.bjango.istatmenus.fans.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2019-09-23)
  [Loaded] com.bjango.istatmenus.installerhelper.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2019-09-23)
  [Running] com.docker.vmnetd.plist (Docker Inc - installed 2019-08-01)
  [Loaded] com.google.keystone.daemon.plist (Google, Inc. - installed 2019-09-23)
  [Loaded] com.macpaw.CleanMyMac3.Agent.plist (MacPaw Inc. - installed 2019-06-08)
  [Loaded] com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2019-09-11)
  [Not Loaded] com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist (? 0  - installed )
  [Loaded] com.safervpn.HelperTool.plist (Safer Social Ltd. - installed 2017-08-02)
  [Loaded] de.appsolute.mampprohelper.plist (? 26ff81e4  - installed 2017-09-28)
  [Loaded] keybase.Helper.plist (Keybase, Inc. - installed 2017-08-04)
  [Not Loaded] org.virtualbox.startup.plist (? 700b9385  - installed 2019-05-30)

User Launch Agents:
  [Loaded] com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist (? 0  - installed 2019-05-29)
  [Loaded] com.dropbox.DropboxMacUpdate.agent.plist (Dropbox, Inc. - installed 2019-08-23)
  [Loaded] com.logmein.GoToMeeting.G2MUpdate.plist (LogMeIn, Inc. - installed 2019-09-03)
  [Loaded] com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist (? 0  - installed 2019-05-29)
  [Running] com.spotify.webhelper.plist (Spotify - installed 2019-06-01)
  [Not Loaded] org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist (Oracle America, Inc. - installed 2019-05-29)

User Login Items:
  Backup and Sync.app (Google, Inc. - installed 2019-07-15)
    (Application - /Applications/Backup and Sync.app)

  Dropbox.app (Dropbox, Inc. - installed 2019-09-18)
    (Application - /Applications/Dropbox.app)

  Jumpcut.app (Steve COOK - installed 2019-09-20)
    (Application - /Applications/Jumpcut.app)

  Thyme.app (? - installed 2017-07-23)
    (Application - /Applications/Thyme.app)

  Time Zone Converter and Clock.app (App Store - installed 2019-09-06)
    (Application - /Applications/Time Zone Converter and Clock.app)

  Vanilla.app (Matthew Palmer - installed 2019-08-30)
    (Application - /Applications/Vanilla.app)

Internet Plug-ins:
  AdobeAAMDetect: 3.0.0.0 (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2017-10-02)
  AdobeExManDetect: AdobeExManDetect 1.1.0.0 (? - installed 2017-08-23)

Audio Plug-ins:
  AirPlay: 2.0 (Apple - installed 2019-06-13)
  BridgeAudioSP: 5.46 (Apple - installed 2019-06-13)
  iSightAudio: 7.7.3 (Apple - installed 2019-06-13)
  AppleAVBAudio: 740.1 (Apple - installed 2019-06-13)
  SoundBunny: 1.1.4 (? - installed 2019-06-05)
  BluetoothAudioPlugIn: 6.0.12 (Apple - installed 2019-06-13)
  AppleTimeSyncAudioClock: 1.0 (Apple - installed 2019-06-13)

Safari Extensions:
  OpenIE.safariextz - Parallels - http://www.parallels.com (installed 2019-05-29)

3rd Party Preference Panes:
  FUSE (installed 2019-05-28)
  SwitchResX (installed 2019-07-15)

Time Machine:
  Skip System Files: No
  Auto backup: Yes
  Volumes being backed up: 
    Macintosh HD: Disk size: 239.85 GB - Disk used: 220.80 GB 
  Destinations: 
    S*******2 [Local] (Last used)
      Total size: 2.00 TB
      Total number of backups: 30
      Oldest backup: 2019-07-06 00:07:29
      Last backup: 2019-09-16 14:54:47
  15 local snapshots
  Oldest local snapshot: 2019-09-24 05:46:57
  Last local snapshot: 2019-09-24 22:55:13

Performance:
  System Load: 3.02 (1 min ago) 2.44 (5 min ago) 2.28 (15 min ago)
  Nominal I/O speed: 1.52 MB/s
  File system: 21.26 seconds
  Write speed: 159 MB/s
  Read speed: 534 MB/s

CPU Usage Snapshot:
  Type Overall
  System 4 %
  User 11 %
  Idle 84 %

Top Processes Snapshot by CPU:
  Process (count) CPU (Source - Location)
  Google Chrome Helper (Renderer) (39) 49.60 % (Google, Inc.)
  Activity Monitor 21.98 % (Apple)
  WindowServer 17.40 % (Apple)
  Google Chrome Helper (GPU) 13.18 % (Google, Inc.)
  Google Chrome 13.10 % (Google, Inc.)

Top Processes Snapshot by Memory:
  Process (count) RAM usage (Source - Location)
  Google Chrome Helper (Renderer) (39) 5.14 GB (Google, Inc.)
  kernel_task 1.59 GB (Apple)
  EtreCheckPro 583 MB (Etresoft, Inc.)
  Google Chrome 436 MB (Google, Inc.)
  UEFI.fd,, 402 MB (? - com.docker.hyperkit -A -u -F vms/0/hyperkit.pid -c 8 -m 8192M -s 0:0,hostbridge -s 31,lpc -s 1:0,virtio-vpnkit,path=vpnkit.eth.sock,uuid=a1a396b5-9f58-432e-98a8-0af083cf7a98 -U 49b5fc75-90b3-4e9e-ab43-ccbbad4cbbd2 -s 2:0,ahci-hd,/Users/***/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/Docker.raw -s 3,virtio-sock,guest_cid=3,path=vms/0,guest_forwards=2376;1525 -s 4,ahci-cd,/Applications/Docker.app)

Top Processes Snapshot by Network Use:
  Process (count) Input / Output (Source - Location)
  cloudd 2 MB / 20 KB (Apple)
  mDNSResponder 1 MB / 103 KB (Apple)
  Slack 702 KB / 333 KB (Slack Technologies, Inc.)
  WhatsApp 100 KB / 10 KB (App Store)
  netbiosd 72 KB / 27 KB (Apple)

Top Processes Snapshot by Energy Use:
  Process (count) Energy (0-100) (Source - Location)
  Google Chrome Helper (Renderer) (39) 12 (Google, Inc.)
  WindowServer 9 (Apple)
  mds_stores 4 (Apple)
  Google Chrome Helper (GPU) 3 (Google, Inc.)
  Activity Monitor 3 (Apple)

Virtual Memory Information:
  Physical RAM: 16 GB

  Free RAM: 75 MB
  Used RAM: 13.27 GB
  Cached files: 2.65 GB

  Available RAM: 2.73 GB
  Swap Used: 0 B

Software Installs (past 30 days):
  Install Date Name (Version)
  2019-09-06 Time Zone Converter and Clock (1.5.6)
  2019-09-06 WhatsApp (0.3.4480)
  2019-09-07 Noko (1.3.3)
  2019-09-11 Microsoft AutoUpdate (4.15.19090802)
  2019-09-17 EasyRes (1.1.2)

Diagnostics Information (past 7 days):
  2019-09-24 23:31:53 bird High CPU Use
    Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocsDaemon.framework/Versions/A/Support/bird

  2019-09-24 19:51:38 Kernel Panic
    Details:
      panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801c6db92d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801c6be
      3da, type 14=page fault, registers:

    3rd party kernel extensions: 
      com.bitgapp.eqMac2Driver
      com.globaldelight.driver.Boom2Device
      net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio
      org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
      org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp
      org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
      org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB

  2019-09-24 19:31:24 Backup and Sync.app High CPU Use
    Executable: /Applications/Backup and Sync.app

  2019-09-24 14:18:56 git Crash
    Executable: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
    Details:
      dyld2 mode

  2019-09-23 23:47:14 signpost_reporter High CPU Use
    Executable: /usr/libexec/signpost_reporter

  2019-09-22 20:01:13 suggestd High CPU Use
    Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSuggestions.framework/Versions/A/Support/suggestd

  2019-09-22 18:45:43 Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5.app High CPU Use
    Executable: /Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5/Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.5.app

  2019-09-22 16:50:33 Sequel Pro.app Crash
    Executable: /Applications/Sequel Pro.app

  2019-09-22 15:34:44 ScreenFlow.app Crash
    Executable: /Applications/ScreenFlow.app

  2019-09-21 11:55:33 Finder.app High CPU Use
    Executable: /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app

  2019-09-20 15:29:47 callservicesd Crash
    Executable: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/callservicesd
    Details:
      dyld3 mode

  2019-09-20 15:29:46 Visual Studio Code.app Crash
    Executable: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app

  2019-09-18 21:16:58 WhatsApp.app Crash
    Executable: /Applications/WhatsApp.app


End of report
```

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14899/313842 and the linked article and as mentioned, it's technical

Comment: You have SIP and security updates disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suspects for kernel panics are always 3rd party kexts.

I don't know all the apps you have installed on there, so you may need further testing/updating, but this is what I can see straight away…

Boom2 is a known crasher. Lose that & see what happens.
CleanMyMac is out of date. V4 has been out a while, idk if v3 is still OK on Mojave.
See [What is com.apple.bird? Why does it grow so big?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220007/what-is-com-apple-bird-why-does-it-grow-so-big) for some help on Bird, which is the iCloud sync EtreCheck is complaining about.
CC2015 is getting very old.

Uninstall any other 3rd party apps with background kexts if panics still happen.
It's a process of elimination.

Also, your drive is far too full. You need to keep between 10 & 20% free space, ironically more on smaller drives.

Comment: Thanks! That didn't solve my problem (I think it's related to Backup and Sync with folder on SD Card), but it's the correct advice. I'll accept this as the answer.