# x86 CPU CATERR panic

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, kernel-panic

I'm experiencing frequent x86 CPU CATERR panics on a new 2020 13-inch mbp. Here are three logs:

#1

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff021cef7b4): x86 CPU CATERR detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS version: 17P4534
macOS version: 19E2265
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Mon Mar 2 18:54:27 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 6A2C720E-996F-3833-8971-CB16C75A4094
iBoot version: iBoot-5540.105.2
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x10001000100
PCIeUp link state: 0x89473611
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide: 0x0000000019cb8000
Kernel text base: 0xfffffff020cbc000
mach_absolute_time: 0x4094570df27
Epoch Time: sec usec
Boot : 0x5ec7ec85 0x00002159
Sleep : 0x5ed13873 0x000c7ce8
Wake : 0x5ed13876 0x000a50fa
Calendar: 0x5ed14199 0x0009c230

Panicked task 0xffffffe000700800: 3487 pages, 221 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe000a4fa18, backtrace: 0xffffffe0001434b0, tid: 368
lr: 0xfffffff021580764 fp: 0xffffffe0001434f0
lr: 0xfffffff0215805c0 fp: 0xffffffe000143560
lr: 0xfffffff02169ae7c fp: 0xffffffe000143610
lr: 0xfffffff021b4962c fp: 0xffffffe000143620
lr: 0xfffffff02157ff28 fp: 0xffffffe000143990
lr: 0xfffffff021580280 fp: 0xffffffe0001439e0
lr: 0xfffffff0223b6934 fp: 0xffffffe000143a00
lr: 0xfffffff021cef7b4 fp: 0xffffffe000143a30
lr: 0xfffffff021ce0be4 fp: 0xffffffe000143aa0
lr: 0xfffffff021ce2b0c fp: 0xffffffe000143b50
lr: 0xfffffff021ce031c fp: 0xffffffe000143be0
lr: 0xfffffff021ca7780 fp: 0xffffffe000143c10
lr: 0xfffffff021ab6abc fp: 0xffffffe000143c50
lr: 0xfffffff021ab6340 fp: 0xffffffe000143c90
lr: 0xfffffff021b54514 fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

#2

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff00a8213dc): x86 CPU CATERR detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS version: 17P5300
macOS version: 19F101
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:16:42 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 123C59BB-125A-31AF-A916-AAF729BE6BE8
iBoot version: iBoot-5540.125.4
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x7
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x10001000100
PCIeUp link state: 0x89473611
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide: 0x00000000027e8000
Kernel text base: 0xfffffff0097ec000
mach_absolute_time: 0x15648414f08
Epoch Time: sec usec
Boot : 0x5ed62607 0x000bc5f4
Sleep : 0x5ed79bb6 0x00042e93
Wake : 0x5ed79eaa 0x00094cb4
Calendar: 0x5ed7e5c4 0x000aaa6f

Panicked task 0xffffffe000797c00: 3365 pages, 219 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe000b6cfd8, backtrace: 0xffffffe0165134b0, tid: 324
lr: 0xfffffff00a0b0764 fp: 0xffffffe0165134f0
lr: 0xfffffff00a0b05c0 fp: 0xffffffe016513560
lr: 0xfffffff00a1cb1e0 fp: 0xffffffe016513610
lr: 0xfffffff00a67962c fp: 0xffffffe016513620
lr: 0xfffffff00a0aff28 fp: 0xffffffe016513990
lr: 0xfffffff00a0b0280 fp: 0xffffffe0165139e0
lr: 0xfffffff00aee6934 fp: 0xffffffe016513a00
lr: 0xfffffff00a8213dc fp: 0xffffffe016513a30
lr: 0xfffffff00a81280c fp: 0xffffffe016513aa0
lr: 0xfffffff00a814734 fp: 0xffffffe016513b50
lr: 0xfffffff00a811f44 fp: 0xffffffe016513be0
lr: 0xfffffff00a7d93a8 fp: 0xffffffe016513c10
lr: 0xfffffff00a5e75d8 fp: 0xffffffe016513c50
lr: 0xfffffff00a5e6e5c fp: 0xffffffe016513c90
lr: 0xfffffff00a684514 fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

#3

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff01c25d3dc): x86 CPU CATERR detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS version: 17P5300
macOS version: 19F101
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Tue May 26 20:16:42 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.121.2~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 123C59BB-125A-31AF-A916-AAF729BE6BE8
iBoot version: iBoot-5540.125.4
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x10001000100
PCIeUp link state: 0x89473614
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:     0x0000000014224000
Kernel text base: 0xfffffff01b228000
mach_absolute_time: 0x82b4a4e815f
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x5eda9808 0x000a5d1e
  Sleep   : 0x5ee846dc 0x0009d6d3
  Wake    : 0x5ee84f1d 0x000cd1a7
  Calendar: 0x5ee8b099 0x0008b6db

Panicked task 0xffffffe0000e1e00: 3375 pages, 219 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe000376f88, backtrace: 0xffffffe016dd34b0, tid: 346
          lr: 0xfffffff01baec764  fp: 0xffffffe016dd34f0
          lr: 0xfffffff01baec5c0  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3560
          lr: 0xfffffff01bc071e0  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3610
          lr: 0xfffffff01c0b562c  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3620
          lr: 0xfffffff01baebf28  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3990
          lr: 0xfffffff01baec280  fp: 0xffffffe016dd39e0
          lr: 0xfffffff01c922934  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3a00
          lr: 0xfffffff01c25d3dc  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3a30
          lr: 0xfffffff01c24e80c  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3aa0
          lr: 0xfffffff01c250734  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3b50
          lr: 0xfffffff01c24df44  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3be0
          lr: 0xfffffff01c2153a8  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3c10
          lr: 0xfffffff01c0235d8  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3c50
          lr: 0xfffffff01c022e5c  fp: 0xffffffe016dd3c90
          lr: 0xfffffff01c0c0514  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

What's going on with this machine?

Answer (score 0):

What’s going on is the system is asking you to [look deeper at the software and possibly have the hardware evaluated.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean?) It’s sometimes hard to trace why the panic happened from just the logs.

For you, what is happening for the time when these are logged?

The process we follow is to start with making a paper log so it’s easy to note what you wanted to do or were doing.

- 08 June 1823 - run safari on ask different
- 13 June 0734 - chrome news site
- 13 June 0922 - chrome same news site

So once you have about 10 events, it will help you know if there is a pattern or not a pattern. Then we go through the Apple steps:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553

Often we conclude it’s software and don’t need support. Always we will wipe and reinstall and test without third party apps a few days before we send it for service unless we are sure [we can cause the panic to happen if we figure out what app or action triggers it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14899/5472).

Comment: Then I should move iMovie to the trash according to apple support, and then contact them to see if there is an update...doesn't seem like a solution from them really.

Comment: Why not trash the app and then contact them? Support knows how to walk though making a new account to ensure it’s not content that causes the crash and can feel the data to the developers, it might just be a software bug Apple can fix in the next updates. @user3306356

Comment: I was getting this _every_ time I tried to use Photos or Time Machine, and occasionally other times.  Apple replaced logic board and touch bar, for no change.  Found that somehow Photo library was no longer the "system library"  That made Photos and Time Machine available, but now it panics when asleep!